# OpenMP nested for loop

Tags: for-loop, nested, openmp

Hi I have the following code. Is the inner loop ( for loop in the function Foo ) give parallelized performance? Or Do I have to add anything like "collapse" in the outer loop to get the parallel performance for the inner loop?

```
void X(int i)
{
}
void Foo()
{
   ... Do something
   #pragma omp parallel for
   for( int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i )
   {
       X(i);
   }
}
void main()
{
   #pragma omp parallel for
   for( int k = 0; k < 1000; ++k )
   {
     Foo();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, no, it should not (and does not on my machine).

First of, OpenMP has a value that sets the number of threads it will use, by default it's set to the number of threads available on your system. So even if this was going to work, the first call would already use all the available threads and the second call would be executed sequentially as a result. This value can be modified by calling `omp_set_num_threads(...)`, but it is global, so the above behaviour will remain, i.e. the first call will use all the threads it thinks it has available. The easiest way to remedy this is by adding `num_threads(...)` to the omp pragma and forcing it to ignore that value. Of course you can also use variables in there, so `num_threads(x)` is completely legal where `x` is some integer that does not even need to be known at compile time.

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(2) //Let's say we want 2 threads in this for loop
```

However, this alone is not enough because nesting is, by default, disabled. To enable nesting of OMP parallel regions we simply need to call `omp_set_nested(true);`. It might also be wise to add `omp_set_max_active_levels(2);`, but this is not needed, the default value seems to be larger (I don't actually know what it is, is might simply be unlimited).

So, a simple test program could be something like:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(void) {
    omp_set_nested(true); //Enables nesting. 
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(2) //We will be using 2 threads for the first for loop.
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int tid1 = omp_get_thread_num();
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(2) //And 2 threads for each of the threads in the second loop.
        //This will require a total of 4 threads. 
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            int tid2 = omp_get_thread_num();
            std::string msg =  std::to_string(i) + " " + std::to_string(j) + " " + std::to_string(tid1) + " " + std::to_string(tid2) + "\n";
            std::cerr << msg;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This will tell use what combination of threads `(tid1, tid2)` runs each combination of `(i, j)`, the output is of the form `i j tid1 tid2`. If we comment out `omp_set_nested(true);` we'll notice that `tid2` is always `0`, meaning that the inner loop does not execute in parallel.

A note regarding the output, both `cout`and `cerr` are thread-safe, but that only applies to single calls to the operator `<<`. So using something like `std::cout << i << " " << j << ...` gives you lots of calls to that operator from different threads and might give you some interleaved parts from different threads (you can try yourself, it won't happen too often but it can). That's why we construct a string and then issue a single call to `<<`.

And, as always when trying to run something in parallel, how many threads you want to use in each level will depend on both the type of operations they will be doing and the machine you're running it on. It's probably best to try it and play around a bit if you want to achieve optimal performance. Just make sure the total number of threads (the product of threads in the nested loops) doesn't exceed the number of threads available on your system, that usually slows things down.

Comment: if I set `omp_set_max_active_levels(2)` inside a function, does it take effect through out the whole code, i.e. will it take effect in a separate function too?

Comment: First a disclaimer, I don't actually know how exactly this is implemented in OpenMP, but lets assume it affects some global variable defined by whatever OMP library you use, which sounds reasonable. In that case, it should work just fine. That said, I would avoid calling this inside any parallel regions without looking at some documentation to make sure nothing weird happens.

Comment: According to: https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu125.html what I said earlier is probably true.

Comment: I'm calling that in a sequential region, and I want nested parallelism to happen in every relevant function with out calling that every time. Also what is the default value of the `max_active_levels` is it 1 or is it unlimited

Comment: That is probably implementation define, but a trivial way to check for your system would be to call `omp_get_max_active_levels()` before setting anything.